# converting a wire value to an integer in verilog

Tags: syntax, binary, integer, verilog

I want to convert the data in a wire to an integer. For example:

```
wire [2:0] w = 3'b101;
```

I want a method that converts this to '5' and stores it in an integer. How can I do that in a better way than this:

```
j=1;
for(i=0; i<=2; i=i+1)
begin
  a=a+(w[i]*j);   
  j=j*2;
end
```

Also, how do I convert it back to binary once I have the value in an integer? This seems a clumsy way. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy! Conversion is automatic in verilog if you assign to an integer. In verilog, all the data types are just collection on bits.

```
integer my_int;
always @( w )
    my_int = w;
```

Comment: thank you. I also want to do the reverse, as in w=my_int. is it allowed?

Comment: It is, but you'll only get the 3 LSBs of `my_int` stored in `w`. For example, if the number `'d16` (`10000`) is in `my_int`, `w` will become= `3'b000`

Comment: got it. Thank you. It means I just have to take care to keep w long enough.

Answer (score 2):

As Marty said : conversion between bit vectors and integers is automatic. 
But there are a number of pitfalls. They are obvious if you keep in mind that an integer is a 32 bit signed value.

- Don't try to assign e.g. a 40 bit value to an integer.
- Default bit vector are unsigned so a 32 bit vector may become negative when it is an integer.
- The opposite is also true: a negative integer e.g. -3 will become an 8 vector with value 8'b11111101

I don't know why you want to convert to an integer and back. I just want to point out that arithmetic operations are fully supported on signed and unsigned bit vectors. In fact they are more powerful as there is no 32-bit limit:

```
reg [127:0] huge_counter;
...
   always @(posedge clk)
      huge_counter <= huge_counter + 128'h1;
```

Also using a vector as index is supported:

```
wire [11:0] address;
reg  [ 7:0] memory [0:4095];
...
   assign read_data = memory[address];
```